# Implementing Handover protocol for facebook chatbot throws error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My primary receiver is my dialogflow chatbot and my second one is the page inbox. I want to switch from the chatbot to the inbox by implementing:

```
request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/pass_thread_control',
    qs: {'access_token': 'pageAccessToken'},
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        recipient: {
            id: 'userIdFromRequest'
        },
        target_app_id: 'pageInboxAppId'
    },
}, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
    console.log('BODY PASS THREAD CONTROL: ', body);
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> (#10) Only available to Primary and Secondary Receivers

---

When I try to get the secondary receivers:

```
request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/secondary_receivers?fields=id,name&access_token=<page-access-token>',
    qs: {'access_token': <page-access-token>},
    method: 'GET',
}, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
    console.log('BODY SECONDARY RECEIVERS: ', body);
});
```

I will get this error:

> (#10) Only Main Receiver can call this API

But my chatbot IS the main receiver. I set in in `page settings` --> `messenger platform`.

I found out that this used to be a facebook bug, but it should have been fixed now.

Does someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The `app_roles` parameter is missing in the web hook request. May it could have something to do with it?

Another mistake could be the userId. I took the senderId. The receiverId encounters an authorization error with errorCode 1 and the message "An unknown error occurred". I'm not sure which one is correct.<

**UPDATE 2**

The receiverId seems to be correct. The second request works with it. But still not the first: 500 internal server error...

Comment: _“I found out that this used to be a facebook bug, but it should have been fixed now.”_ - maybe the effects of the bug still linger though, if you did your setup before that? In that case, I’d try removing the subscriptions from the page, and add them again first.

Comment: It was fixed in early 2018 and my setup was 2 days ago. Therefore, it should not be the problem. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, it works now. Maybe they changed anything in the backend.